# JIRA - Is there any way to add "Epic" as a column in the "Issues" view?

Tags: jira, project-management, agile-project-management

I'm using free Jira in Chrome.

I designed my Kanban board so that the swimlanes are the epics.

I'd like to add a column that specifics which epic each issue belongs to in the "Issues" view, but I can't find a way to do this (see photo below).

Any insight you have would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!

[image]

Comment: @Slotheroo thank you so much!! You're a life saver. I tried what you told me to do and I got exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a recently updated version of the issues project view in Cloud. AFAIK there is no way to change the columns displayed here.

If you clicked where it says "Go to advanced search" you'll navigate away from the project to the general Jira search page (called the Issue Navigator) which is a view that is not specific to any one project, but you can do project-specific searches and save them as filters. In the List View here you can add/remove columns, such as the Epic Link field, which is what you're looking for.